# 90's/early 2000's movie involving an evil prince and wizard time traveling to a medieval world attraction place

Tags: identify-this-movie

US movie. Judging from what I remember, it seems that this movie was made for TV rather than a theatrical release (though I maybe wrong). The Evil Prince and Wizard both had beards and mustaches and whenever the wizard was casting magic, a green aura would appear.

Story Points

- The movie first starts with the two villains being captured and transported via a caged carriage. The wizard uses his magic for the two of them to break free and they escape, but they are very quickly recaptured. A few scenes later, we see the two villains in a dungeon, and the wizard uses his magic again to control the jailer to set them free. After being set free, the wizard then casts a spell to allow the both of them to travel to the present.
- We then see our protagonists (2 male and 1 female). They watch a commercial promoting a medieval world attraction thing (one thing that I remember about the commercial was when the narrator mentioned "lady/damsel in distress", a woman wielding a sword says "who are you calling a lady/damsel in distress" and lunges the sword unto the camera). They become interested and go to this medieval place (the attraction is set in a castle btw).
- When they arrive, they meet the owner of the attraction; an old bearded man dressed as a king (I think he was in his late 50's or early 60's). He then shows them around and reveals that most of the people working there are apparently robots. They then dress in medieval clothing (one of the men wears a jester costume)
- Then a storm comes in and the villains appear. The owner then meets them as he comes to investigate and asks if he could help them. The prince then smiles and says that he can and presumably capture him.
- I think what happens next is the protagonists are transported to the past (though they are still at the castle).
- At one point, theres a scene where the villains (along with a few of his armored guards) feed a pig/cow to a dragon.
- Many scenes later, the protagonists then find another wizard (who is very elderly) who has been locked up in a cell. After freeing him, we then cut to a scene where the wizard is eating food in a large dining table. He reveals that the wizard in league with the prince was a student of his (even stating that he was like a son to him).
- When the protagonist dressed as a jester disbelieves his claim as a wizard, the elderly wizard then levitates him (jester even enjoys the levitation and even dances a bit).
- At some point, the villains then capture the woman protagonist, and they make a plan to rescue her and the attraction owner. They go to the dragon (who can talk) and the elderly wizard convinces him to help them. The dragon scares away the princes guards.
- The elderly wizard and jester fight the princes wizard whilst the other protagonist fights the prince. The elderly wizard then pins down the evil wizard and forces him to cast a spell that will make him lose his powers. The evil wizard then says some magic words and informs them that he is now powerless. The protagonist then fights the prince and wins.
- The scene then cuts to the heroes outside, with the jailer dragging away the villains. The jester tries to get a high-five from the elderly wizard, but the gesture only confuses the wizard. When jester informs him that he's slap his hand, the wizard asks why would he do that.
- The heroes are then transported back in their own time and the owner is greeted by his staff and robots.

Comment: With a synopsis like this, if @Walt can't find this one, he deserves to *lose* reputation points :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm almost positive you're after the low budget [Teen Knight](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0152946/combined) (AKA Medieval Park) from 1999.

> **Young Kris Lemche along with several other teens wins a trip to a kind Medieval Times resort which gets transported back to some real medieval times in Teen Knight. It's all been done by a wizard back then who's got some extraordinary powers** and he'd like to unleash the advances of the future in a power play back in his own era.
>
> **So what looks like a nice Westworld type romp gets very real just like in Westworld. But the robots stay behind and it's only the humans and the castle with all modern advances that go back. Oh, and a computer created dragon becomes the real mccoy.**
>
> The evil genius behind all of this is a Mordred like character played with some relish and a bit too free a rein from the director, by Marc Robinson. Fortunately there's also a Merlin character who looks just Paul Soles the owner of the Medieval Times like resort.

Pretty sure everything you said is there (The villain's a bearded prince, the girls get kidnapped etc.) You can see the trailer [here](http://www.videodetective.com/movies/teen-knight/868810), and here's a scene with the jester and a dragon:

Comment: That is definitely the one ! Thank you very much Walt ^^

Comment: Wahey! Good job